# plot excel graph with non-numerical values

Tags: excel, plot, graph

I'm a quite new Microsoft's excel user, and I'm stuck plotting a graph.
It is a graph containing as X values a couple month-year and as Y values, different smartphone screen resolutions. I want to plot a graph representing the evolution, during years, of screen resolutions.

My problem is that I cannot plot nothing because excel doesn't recognise (obviously) numeric values, because resolutions are wrote like 1024x768 etc.

How can I create a graph with these requirements?
Googling hasn't give me solutions for now.

thank you guys in advance!

## EDIT

Here you are with a sample of data:
[image]
I want to use "Years" column as values on the x-axis (ordered from the oldest date) and the "Resolution" field on the y-axis, to highlight how screen resolutions evolved during years.

Thank you!

Comment: The first step might be to convert resolutions like 1024X768 into numbers of pixels like 786432 then they would be numeric values. We would need to see sample data and what you have tried so far to offer help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My first problem is that I have a string field containing for example 1024x768 and not computable numerical values. 

I'll now edit the post with a example of data.

Comment: I think the easiest way to handle the resolution if it is a letter X in the middle would be to use text to columns and select X as the delimiter, then you can multiply the resulting columns or just focus on the X-resolution, etc. For the dates I personally would work in quarters over that sort of range because Excel makes such a mess of date axes i.e. use =YEAR(A2)+(MONTH(A2)-1)/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I have used the following formula to get the year (it looks like text, I can't really tell)

```
=RIGHT(A2,4)+(LEFT(A2,2)-1)/12
```

and this to get the number of pixels in millions:-

```
=LEFT(E2,FIND("x",E2)-1)*RIGHT(E2,LEN(E2)-FIND("x",E2))/10^6
```

and when you use a scatter it ends up looking like this:-

[image]

Comment: sorry for the delay on answering, I think this is the best way to plot those data. Thank you so much!